# I dont know, is it correct process OR not - salesforce session id passing between apps

Tags: managed-extension

I am building an app which is between salesforce and java system.

salesforce will do some callouts to java and it return some response for every callout in synchronous process.

but in some cases i want to send response in asynchronous process.

My plan for this is : i want to pass salesforce session id to java system with the callout request and i will store and reuse the same session id for asynchronous call after 1 or 2 mins to send response back to salesforce.

any suggestions plz.

is it right process to pass session id between two system ..?

Answer (score 3):

What you describe architecturally is precisely how the workflow outbound message action works.

- Workflow is triggered upon some insert or update.
- All workflow criteria are met
- Salesforce enqueues outbound SOAP message

For the outbound message:

- You need to configure fields are to be included
- You also need to identify the a user identity
- You identify a session id that can be used to call back to Salesforce

In fact, based on what you described, I would probably start with workflow outbound message as an option on the table. And then decide whether it fits the bill.

So could you roll your own such integration? I don't see why not. You'll just want to be cautious of a few things:

- Making sure the round trip happens in a timely fashion and the session id is not lost between the outbound call and the callback
- Ensuring the user who owns the session (whoever that is) has perms to perform the logic you want them to. So for this reason, I would probably suggest it be a custom Apex web service you call back to.
- Keeping the session ID secure in the external system. If you make it easy to compromise, you are inviting data theft.